# Xamarin UI Test Android Date Picker (On Hold)

Tags: xamarin, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I'm working with Xamarin UI Test (1.0.0). I'm trying to write an extension method that will update the selected date. 
Here is what I wrote so far. It works with iOS and Android 4.x. it does not work with Android 5.x.

```
   public static void EnterDate(this IApp app, string datePickerStyleId, DateTime date)
    {
        var array = app.Query(datePickerStyleId);
        if (array.Length == 0)
            return;
        foreach (var picker in array)
        {
            var newMonth = date.ToString("MMM");
            var newDay = date.Day.ToString();
            var newYear = date.Year.ToString();
            if (app.IsAndroid())
            {
                app.Tap(picker.Label);
                //if device OS > 5 try scrolll up
                app.Repl();
                app.Screenshot("Date Picker");
                app.Tap("month");
                app.EnterText(newMonth);
                app.PressEnter();
                app.Tap("day");
                app.EnterText(newDay);
                app.PressEnter();
                app.Tap("year");
                app.EnterText(newYear);
                app.PressEnter();
                app.ClickDone();
                app.Screenshot("Page After Changing Date");
                app.ClickButton("Ok");
            }
            else if (app.IsIOS())
            {
                app.Tap(picker.Id);
                app.Screenshot("Date Picker");
                var currentDate = picker.Text;
                var split = currentDate.Split(' ');
                var currentMonth = split[0];
                var currentDay = split[1].Remove(split[1].Length - 1);
                var currentYear = split[2];
                if (!newMonth.Equals(currentMonth))
                {
                    app.Tap(newMonth);
                }
                if (!newDay.Equals(currentDay))
                {
                    app.Tap(newDay);
                }
                if (!newYear.Equals(currentYear))
                {
                    app.Tap(newYear);
                }
                app.ClickButton("Done");
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem that I'm running into is that I can't figure out how to select a certain date. App.ScrollUp()/.ScrollDown() do work to navigate to different months. Although, I haven't found to determine the current month and then pick a day. Here is the output from the tree command of the Repl() tool.

> > > tree                                                                        [[object CalabashRootView] > ... > FrameLayout]                                   [FrameLayout] id: "content"                                                       [LinearLayout] id: "parentPanel"                                                  [FrameLayout] id: "customPanel"                                                   [FrameLayout] id: "custom"                                                        [DatePicker > LinearLayout] id: "datePicker"                                      [LinearLayout] id: "day_picker_selector_layout"
> > >                     [TextView] id: "date_picker_header" text: "Thursday"
> > >                     [LinearLayout] id: "date_picker_month_day_year_layout"
> > >                       [LinearLayout] id: "date_picker_month_and_day_layout",  label: "August 6"
> > >                         [TextView] id: "date_picker_month" text: "AUG"
> > >                         [TextView] id: "date_picker_day" text: "6"
> > >                       [TextView] id: "date_picker_year" text: "2015"
> > >                   [AccessibleDateAnimator > ... > SimpleMonthView] id: "animator",  label: "Month grid of days: August 6"
> > >             [LinearLayout] id: "buttonPanel"
> > >               [Button] id: "button2" text: "Cancel"
> > >               [Button] id: "button1" text: "OK"

Does anybody know or have a method to select the date for Xamarin UI test that will work on iOS and Android (4.x and 5.x)?

Comment: My company has moved away from Xamarin Forms so this question is no longer relevant. After working with Xamarin Support the issue is related to Android Material Design. Support recommend using a Blackfoot but I never got it work.

Comment: Sorry. Backdoor not Blackfoot.

Comment: .....hi, I was able to resolve mine by using app.Tap("datepicker_id"); followed by app.Tap("December");, app.Tap("12");, the year was the tricky part as i could only select the year showing on the view at the current time....so I did successive app.Tap's till i reached the desired year....like app.Tap("2012"); followed by app.Tap("2006"); ...and so on.........I also noticed something else...which was after the datepicker popup is selected a call on "tree" shows all the parameters of the datepicker....there were no id's but if one could add separate id's to day,month and year that might help...